# INTERSECT 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, intersection

> I need to **intersect two tables** based
>   on a column,in both tables.

Here's my code snippet :

```
SELECT b.VisitID,  b.CarrierName, b.PhoneNum, b.PatientName, b.SubscriberID, b.SubscriberName, 
        b.ChartNum, b.DoB, b.SubscriberEmp, b.ServiceDate, b.ProviderName, b.CPTCode, b.AgingDate, 
        b.BalanceAmt, f.FollowUpNote, f.InternalStatusCode FROM billing b JOIN followup f 
        USING (VisitID) WHERE b.VisitID = f.VisitID
```

In the 'followup' table I've 281 rows AND 'billing' table contains 2098 rows. When I execute this query I'm getting 481 rows.

Did anyone faces this sort of problem? 
Could you help me to INTERSECT these tables?

Thanx in advance..

Comment: seems to me that you have some records in the 'billing' table with the same VisitID value that are matched to multiple records in the 'followup' table... I guess you need to find some other common information between the two tables that can help you filter the results

Comment: To expand on shil88's comments, if it doesn't matter which of the "duplicate" rows you use, you can use the `GROUP BY` clause. Alternately, you can use the `UNIQUE` keyword in your table definition to prevent duplicate `VisitID`s from occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you like to do a left join here (not an inner join as in your example):

```
SELECT b.VisitID,  b.CarrierName, b.PhoneNum, b.PatientName,
  b.SubscriberID, b.SubscriberName, b.ChartNum, b.DoB,
  b.SubscriberEmp, b.ServiceDate, b.ProviderName, b.CPTCode,
  b.AgingDate, b.BalanceAmt,
  f.FollowUpNote, f.InternalStatusCode
FROM billing b
LEFT JOIN followup f ON b.VisitID = f.VisitID
```

This will also return rows from the 'billing' table that don't have corresponding fields in the 'followup' table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you'd be very likely to have multiple follow ups.  Thus the 481 records from the notes table is likely accurate.

Perhaps add an

```
ORDER BY b.SubscriberID
```

to JochenJung's answer above and accept that you have the right number of rows.
alternately a

```
GROUP BY b.SubscriberID
```

Would give you one row per customer